URL journey map chart (Customer Journey Map, CJM)
I have this dataframe:
    client_id   date_time   url steps
0   506 2024-08-20 05:00:00 google.com/page_1   step_1
1   506 2024-08-20 05:01:00 google.com/page_2   step_2
2   506 2024-08-20 05:04:00 google.com/page_4   step_3
3   997 2024-08-20 16:10:00 google.com/page_1   step_1
4   997 2024-08-20 16:12:00 google.com/page_7   step_2
5   1588    2024-08-20 12:55:00 google.com/page_12  step_1
6   1588    2024-08-20 12:56:00 google.com/page_2   step_2
7   1588    2024-08-20 12:57:00 google.com/page_4   step_3

My Dataframe
How to build a journey map?
I want to see this:
Picture_1
Also there is an example of chart:
Picture_2
May be you know any python library?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
